# RViz rendering problem

Tags: rviz, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I found RViz did not show an object correctly which comes in front of other further one.
Especially this seems to happen when you see them from a distance.

Video:
https://youtu.be/VhleiBXNV2s

My environment:
Ubuntu 16.04, Kinectic Kame(installed by ros-kinetic-desktop-full) with Geforce GTX 740

Is there any good way to avoid this issue?
What I can think of is... to modify material properties of markers by inheriting. Will it work?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264389/rviz-rendering-problem/) by [Lain Iwakura](https://answers.ros.org/users/25630/lain-iwakura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check the RViz [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues) to see if this has already been reported? Especially [#1067](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1067) seems similar.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lain Iwakura](https://answers.ros.org/users/25630/lain-iwakura/) on 2017-06-22**:
Totally same. Thank you very much.